# Using "parallel_tests" gem with Rails and Rspec and my model's test run normally, but my controllers tests fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I'm trying to use "parallel_tests" gem https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests with my Rspec tests. And with my models it work's fine. But with most of my controllers it gives me errors. While the Rspec still runs normally - no errors.

Test example:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Dashboard::GaugesController, :type => :controller do
  let!(:team) { create(:team) }
  let!(:user) { create(:user, selected_team: team, :slackid => 'SLACKID1') }
  let!(:team_user_admin) { create(:team_user, team: team, user: user, role: :admin) }

  describe 'with auth user' do
    before { sign_in user }
    describe 'GET /' do
      specify 'open gauges page' do
        get :index
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
        expect(response).to render_template(:index)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Error when running rspecs with parallel gem:

```
rake parallel:spec[^spec/controllers/dashboard/gauges_controllers_spec.rb]                                                                                                              [ruby-2.2.3@wyzyr]
Using recorded test runtime
1 processes for 1 specs, ~ 1 specs per process
F

Failures:

  1) Dashboard::GaugesController with auth user GET / open gauges page
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
       expected the response to have status code :ok (200) but it was :found (302)
     # ./spec/controllers/dashboard/gauges_controllers_spec.rb:13:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.46955 seconds (files took 5.43 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/dashboard/gauges_controllers_spec.rb:11 # Dashboard::GaugesController with auth user GET / open gauges page
```

Rspec results:

```
rspec ./spec/controllers/dashboard/gauges_controllers_spec.rb                                                                                                                           [ruby-2.2.3@wyzyr]
.

Finished in 0.53304 seconds (files took 5.25 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Any suggestion where to dig will be really appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I posted and issue related to this problem to [github.com/grosser/parallel_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/issues/548) repo. Will post an update here.